# Clickable slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, clickable

Am starting over here...I am trying to set up a very simple click-able slide show such as used on this page, but horizontal rather than vertical.

http://benhulse.com/Look-of-the-Games

I am trying to use this plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html

Their basic script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
```

I am a jquery beginner so am not sure how to implement the following default option into the script:

```
prevNextEvent:'click.cycle',// event which drives the manual transition to the previous or next slide
```

I do not want any effects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your requirement to scroll horizontally can be set fx as "scrollLeft"

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
fx:      'scrollLeft', 
speedIn:  2000, 
speedOut: 500, 
easeIn:  'easeInCirc', 
easeOut: 'easeOutBounce', 
delay:   -2000 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks!...how do I make it click-able?

Answer (score 0):

To continue to the next slide on click, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
    $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    $(".slideshow").click(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('next');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKs2z/1/

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the code! Am really close now...but it's still going automatically...even with the click function. Am trying to figure out how to make it work *only* on click.

Comment: See edits... You can use `.cycle('pause')` to stop the slideshow on load

Comment: r0m4n...thanks so much. That did it! Thank you for your patience! :)